# Wrapping C struct to Ruby

Tags: c, ruby

How to initialize C Struct and wrap it as Ruby class as parameter of another Ruby object? I am rewriting the memory, but don't know, how to fix it.

Ruby code, I want to create instances of Person class and add Address variable into them, which is another class:

```
require_relative 'my_extension'

class Address
  def inspect
    "Replaced #inspect: <Address: town:#{town}>"
  end
end

class Person
    def initialize
        puts "init"
    end

    def print()
        puts "Addr class #{@addr.inspect}"
    end
end

foo1=Person.new
foo1.add_address("London")
foo1.print
foo2=Person.new
foo2.add_address("Paris")
foo1.print
foo2.print
foo1.print
```

C code, extending Ruby:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ruby.h"

struct Address {
    char * town;
};

static VALUE get_addr(VALUE self) {
    return rb_iv_get(self,"@addr");
}

static VALUE wrap_address_get_town(VALUE self) {

    struct Address * address;
    Data_Get_Struct(self, struct Address, address);
    return rb_str_new2(address->town);
}


VALUE foo_class;
VALUE address_wrapper_class;


void free_m(){
    printf("free\n");//just for test
}

void add_address_t(VALUE self,VALUE new_town){
    printf("add_address\n");
    /*init new struct and add value to it*/
    struct Address addr;
    addr.town=StringValuePtr(new_town);

    /*wrap struct*/
    VALUE wrapped_address=Data_Wrap_Struct(address_wrapper_class, 0, free_m,&addr);

    /*set it as instance variable*/
    rb_iv_set(self,"@addr",wrapped_address);
}

static VALUE foo_class_alloc(VALUE self){
    return self;
}


void Init_my_extension(){
    foo_class = rb_define_class("Person", rb_cObject);

    address_wrapper_class = rb_define_class("Address", rb_cObject);

    rb_define_method(address_wrapper_class, "town", wrap_address_get_town, 0);

    rb_define_method(foo_class, "add_address", add_address_t, 1);

}
```

Output produces unexpected result:

```
init
Addr class Replaced #inspect: <Address: town:London>
init
Addr class Replaced #inspect: <Address: town:Paris> //London expected
Addr class Replaced #inspect: <Address: town:�)> //another problem
Addr class Replaced #inspect: <Address: town:�)>
run
run
free
free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the C routines should be defined as static returning a VALUE. This should be Qnil, if nothing relevant should be returned. There is also another problem, with the `add_address_t` routine - you are wrapping a locally defined struct - it should be allocated with `ALLOC(struct  Address);`

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks. I didn't realize that if I have locally defined struct, the memory for it is released automatically. Or I suppose that it is why I have to allocate it. Is there any difference between use of malloc and ALLOC? Definition as static and returning VALUE is only good practise or it must to be so? It is working without it...

Comment: ALLOC checks if there is enough free memory, and raises an exception if not. It also runs the GC if there is not enough memory. So you should do it yourself, if you don't use ALLOC.

There might be a name clash if the function is not defined as static.

Answer (score 1):

The FFI gem may provide a better way to accomplish what you want to do:

```
require 'ffi'  
module AddressModule
   extend FFI::Library
   ffi_lib '<path to your c library>'

   class Address < FFI::Struct
      layout :address, :string,
   end
end

person = AddressModule::Address.new
person[:address] = "an address"
```

Or whatever.  Check out the FFI documentation at https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki